# Should I use a/an or not in these sentences

Tags: articles

‎Should I use "an" or "a" or nothing in the following?

> It's a product with (an) international quality
>
> You shouldn't buy (an) oil with any of the following
>
> People view (an) oil being refined as a selling point.
>
> Canula oil is (a/an) RBD oil

Also can we say useful ingredients instead of healthy ingredients or does that convey different meaning?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'an international quality'. _A quality_ means a characteristic, but if something _has quality_ it is very good of its kind.

Comment: I decided to go with world class quality.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should I use "a" vs "an"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152/when-should-i-use-a-vs-an) Specifically, [*The question of "a" vs "an" is **always** decided by the **pronunciation** of the word that follows the article.*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/155/2637)

Comment: @KateBunting: If something has "**an** international quality", that means it has some *characteristic* (aspect, trait, quality) that makes it seem "international" (maybe it's designed to appeal to people from all nations, or to jet-setters who stereotypically travel frequently between different nations).

Answer (score 1):

For all the them, choice of *a* or *an* depends on the pronunciation, not the spelling.  The last one

> Canula oil is (a/an) RBD oil

You say "Canula oil is an RBD oil" if you pronounce it "ar bee dee".  But perhaps someone pronounces it "rabid", then he would say "Canula oil is a RBD oil".